# Typescript - group and filters objects in an array according to multiple value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say we have array like:

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'A'
    longitude: 10
    latitude: 12
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name:'B'
    longitude: 10
    latitude: 12
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'C'
    longitude: 11
    latitude: 10
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'D'
    longitude: 11
    latitude: 15
  }
]
```

I want to get an array of object that have the same longitude and latitude like:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'A'
      longitude: 10
      latitude: 12
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name:'B'
      longitude: 10
      latitude: 12
    }
  ]
]
```

The only way that came to mind is looping through the array to get coordinates and the number of objects there, then getting an subarray for each of these coordinates if the length is greater than 1 but the process is quite complex. I am using this in a redux react app, and this is calculated after each state change before rerendering.

Is there a more effective way of doing this? I want to group those with the same longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the data by `longitude` and `latitude`. Next, you need to loop through the data and push your matching objects to a temporary array as shown below. At the end, you can return your temp array.

```js
const arr = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'A',
        longitude: 10,
        latitude: 12,
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'C',
        longitude: 11,
        latitude: 10,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'D',
        longitude: 11,
        latitude: 15,
    },
        {
        id: 1,
        name: 'B',
        longitude: 10,
        latitude: 12
    }
];

function cleanData(data) {
 data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.longitude - b.longitude  || a.latitude - b.latitude;
 });
    let tempArr = [];
    for (let i = data.length - 1; i >=1 ; i--) {
        if (data[i].hasOwnProperty('longitude')) {
                if (data[i].longitude === data[i - 1].longitude &&
                    data[i].latitude === data[i - 1].latitude) {
                    tempArr.push(data[i], data[i - 1]);
                }
                
            } else {
             return;
            }
        
        }
        console.log([...[tempArr]]);
    }

cleanData(arr);
```

Comment: @Ismael123 Is it your expected result?

Comment: Cool. I am glad I was able to help. Would you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Not exactly, the longitude doesn't have to equal the latitude. I'll update the question

Comment: @Ismael123 I rewrote the code based on your change. Are you satisfied?